# How should I be preloading data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails and trying to understand where I should be putting my `.includes`.

For example, I have the following in my controller:

```
@offices = Office
        .includes(:services, :location, :manager)
```

Should this be moved into the Office model?  If so, how should that be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing this in multiple places you can place this logic on the model

#### model

```
class Office < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_includes, -> { includes :services, :location, :manager }
end
```

#### controller

```
@offices = Office.with_includes
```